# Glibc version not found while run .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, glibc

I'm having trouble trying to run a .NET application, when I run the apps, it gives me the output like this:

[image: output]

it says that the particular GLIBC version is not found, while I have the latest version of GLIBC

[image]

So, how to solve this issue?

I'm on ubuntu 22